# Importing JSON file from inside Vue.JS method - Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, electron

I am using a json file to load/write some data. This specific JSON file gets changed quite often.

So with this, how can I import this JSON file from inside a Vue.JS method?

Currently I do this:

```
<script>
import * as settings from '../config/settings.json'
// some other things
</script>
```

But this only gets the json file once and I am not able to get the updates on the json file anymore.

I tried doing something like this:

```
methods: {
  loadJsonFile () {
     import * as settings from '../config/settings.json'
  }
}
```

But it gives an error:

```
error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

How can I dynamically get the updates on this json file based on some trigger (e.g. calling of a method)? Only on code level - not allowed to get modules for this.

Thanks

Comment: The fetch() function could solve your issue. [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: That's because you're importing it as a module. Modules are only loaded once.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how can I load it as a non-module?

Comment: Snce you're in an electron context just use fs